# C# display line of listView in red color if it 's important

Tags: c#, listview

I try to fii a listView from a DataTable, I want to display line in red color if dr[4] (field of importance) = to "Important"
this is the code but if want work

```
 listView2.Items.Clear();
        cn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from note";
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string[] row = { dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString() };
                var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);

                if (dr[4].ToString() == "Important")
                {
                    listViewItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                { listViewItem.ForeColor = Color.Black;}

                listView2.Items.Add(listViewItem);
            }
        }
        cn.Close();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And what exactly is not working?

Comment: What does dr contain?

Comment: @marko: dr is SqlDataReader object here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `Trim` the values before `comparing`:

Try This:

```
if (dr[4].ToString().Trim().Equals("Important"))
 {
   listViewItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dr[4].ToString().Trim().Equals("Important")){  listViewItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;}
```

The fact of missing Trim() lead to error